# Create table by passing name as early defined and value assigned variable in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was trying to create stored procedure for create table as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tableCreation
AS
    DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(30)
    SET @tableName = 'Employee'
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE @tableName (
            id INT NOT NULL
        )
    END
```

but when I execute the procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tableCreation, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '@tableName'.

What is the issue with above procedure or is there any other way to achieve above task?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should build a string containing the SQL you need and then execute that string. This is known as dynamic SQL.

```
create procedure tableCreation
as
   declare @tableName nvarchar(30)
begin

    declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'create table ' + @tableName + '
    (
        id int not null
    )'

    EXEC(@Sql)
end
```

You need to ensure that you validate the value in the @tableName variable before it's passed in to avoid SQL injection attacks

http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html
https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 1):

This might be something that will help, for starters:

```
create procedure tableCreation
as
    declare @tableName nvarchar(30)
    set @tableName = 'Employee'
begin

    declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName + '( id int not null )';

    exec sp_executesql @sql

end
```

But there are better (but still not ideal) ways of using dynamic SQL, for example parametrizing your query which will decrease the changes of your code being prone to SQL Injection. Check out one of the [established articles on this topic](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

But, if you do not pass the table name as a parameter to the procedure, then I guess you're safe from SQL Injection (although this is some kind of obscure and strange behaviour).

Comment: it is working fine,thank you for your support

Comment: @AzharAzmie You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote/mark the correct answer as per Stackoverflow good spirit.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tableCreation
(
    @tableName SYSNAME
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
        CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName + ' (
            id INT NOT NULL
        )'

    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

END
GO

EXEC dbo.tableCreation @tableName = 'Employee'
```